# Python: Efficient way to iterate over a list and a dictionary simultaneously containing similar values

Tags: python, performance, list, dictionary

I have two data structures: a list and a defaultdict dictionary. The list contains an unordered sequence of 300,000 numbers and the dictionary contains the same numbers (not in the same order) as keys with a corresponding value that is some small integer. For instance, the list could be something like: l=[500,800,1500] then the corresponding dictionary is something like d={800:3, 1500:1, 500:4}. My goal is to create another list that has just the corresponding values for each key in the dictionary d in the order of l. For the simple example, I'd want to return [4,3,1] (not [3,1,4]). I have some naive code that works but would take incredibly long to run on the 300,000 numbers.

Here's what I have:

```
for k,v in d.iteritems():
      for i in xrange(len(l)):
           if(l[i]==k):
                 out[i]=v
```

Is there any way to make this more efficient?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loop over the terms in the list, not the key-value pairs in the dictionary:

```
>>> l = [500,800,1500]
>>> d = {800:3, 1500:1, 500:4}
>>> [d[x] for x in l]
[4, 3, 1]
```

Comment: Possibly also using `d.get` with a default in case you don't want an error to be raised on such a large list if something is missing (though you might).

Comment: @Mr.F: the OP said it was a defaultdict, so we're not going to have to worry about missing value exceptions.. if anything, we'd have the other problem, in that we might get a value we don't want if there was a key disagreement..

Comment: Good point. I was going more by the structure used in your solution, which just uses `dict` not `defaultdict`.